# app to app voice call(VOIP) in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

app to app voice call(VOIP) in xamarin forms, we are developing chat application  using xamarin forms in visual studio 2017 so that we like to implement voice call with help of internet like whatsapp, give me suggestion to resolve this issue

Note:I have found one solution using Ozeki voip sip client but i don't know how to do voice (VOIP) call. So Give me sample github link so that i can develop that way

Comment: I use to develope this link(https://github.com/Onotseike/SinchCallDemo/blob/master/SinchCallDemo/SinchCallDemo.Android/IncomingCallScreenActivity.cs), I don't know, how to write incoming activity and outgoing activity for platform specific. Please guide

Comment: I've created a sample in Xamarin with Callkit on iOS but with Twilio VOIP but   if thats what you're looking for:  https://github.com/softsan/callkitsample   and full blog post here: https://medium.com/@san.thanki/callkit-pushkit-twilio-with-xamarin-83553f93be86

Answer (score 1):

> So Give me sample github link so that i can develop that way

**Unfortunately**, There is no such sdk example on github yet.

**Ozeki voip** official web supports the sample explain :

[How to build an Android VoIP client](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_456-how-to-build-an-android-voip-client-voip.html)

[How to build an iPhone / iPad VoIP client](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_457-how-to-build-an-apple-iphone-ipad-voip-client-voip.html)

If not mind using other sdk , you can refert to **PortSIP VoIP** SDK :

[PortSIP VoIP SDK for Xamarin](https://www.portsip.com/download-portsip-voip-sdk/)